# How I can add event_api_destination to cloudwatch rule in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform0.12+

How can i add resource aws_cloudwatch_event_api_destination and aws_cloudwatch_event_connection to resource  aws_cloudwatch_event_rule in terraform?

This Code in below

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "test123_schedule_everyday" {
  name                = "${var.test123_bucket_name}-schedule-everyday-${var.env}"
  description         = "Meter reader get api data every 11:00 PM at lotus"
  schedule_expression = "cron(0 16 * * ? *)"
  is_enabled          = "${var.test123_cloudwatch_is_enable}"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [schedule_expression, description, is_enabled]
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_api_destination" "test123_event_api" {
  name                             = "test-dev-api"
  description                      = "test-dev-api destination"
  invocation_endpoint              = "https://test.com"
  invocation_rate_limit_per_second = "1"
  http_method                      = "GET"
  connection_arn                   = aws_cloudwatch_event_connection.test123_event_connection.arn
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_connection" "test123_event_connection" {
  name               = "test-dev-connection"
  description        = "A connection description"
  authorization_type = "API_KEY"

  auth_parameters {
    api_key {
      key   = "test-key"
      value = "TUVURVJSRUFESU5HOkNCWktXWFU3NzZDS0dGTk5LNjdGWUFVNFFRNE1HV0o3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you experiencing some errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you seek is an [aws_cloudwatch_event_target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target). This allows you to specify your destination as a target for a given rule, as documented in the official [API destinations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html) documentation.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "this" {
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.test123_schedule_everyday.name
  arn  = aws_cloudwatch_event_api_destination.test123_event_api.arn
}
```

Comment: This work. Thank you very much.